# Generic class with multiple types generates errors

Tags: java

I am trying to create the following class using generics:

```
public class IndexSet<T> extends HashMap<T, D extends Duet<T>>
```

But the compiler generates two errors with text "error: > expected", pointing here: `D extends Duet<T>`

I tried to make it another way:

```
public class IndexSet<T> extends HashMap<T, D extends Duet<? extends T>>
```

And even more errors come. I've searched through all the internet, but I see that people are using the exact same syntax. I have no idea, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The correct way is `class IndexSet<T, D extends Duet<T>> extends HashMap<T, D>` or perhaps `class IndexSet<T> extends HashMap<T, ? extends Duet<T>>`

Comment: @Andreas Is your second example valid? I thought wildcards weren't allowed when extending a class or implementing an interface.

Comment: @Slaw DOH!! You're right, it's not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the type parameters on the type you are declaring.

```
public class IndexSet<T, D extends Duet<T>> extends HashMap<T, D> {
```

Comment: But it's possible for sure to create a class IndexSet<T> which extends HashMap<T, T>. So I wanted to create this: `IndexSet<T> extends HashMap<T, AnotherObject<T>>`. And then it got complicated. Is there no another way around?

Comment: @Rawicz You can have `class IndexSet<T> extends HashMap<T, AnotherObject<T>>`. If you want a second type parameter, then you'll need need to declare it. Perhaps it would be helpful to write it first using composition, i.e. `IndexSet` has a `HashMap`/`Map` as a field.